# How to install LaTeX classes in docker image permanently

Tags: docker, latex

I would like to build an docker image for a CI for LaTeX documents. The dollowing is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y -qq texlive-full
COPY *.cls /texmf/tex/latex/
WORKDIR /texmf
RUN texhash
```

When I use this image from one of the document's CIs it is not able to find the customized classes.

What is the problem with my Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find the mistake, but now everything works fine...

```
RUN mkdir -p /root/texmf/tex/latex/myclass/
COPY *.cls /root/texmf/tex/latex/myclass/
COPY figures/* /root/texmf/tex/latex/myclass/figures/
WORKDIR /root/texmf
RUN texhash
```